# Android unable to play video from specific URL

Tags: android, android-videoview, playback

I have run into a problem with playing a video from a specfic URL on Android 6.0 (sony experia mini). If I move the video to another URL I can play it. If I use a phone with Android 5.1 it works without problems.

The URL with the problem:
https://cloudadvice.blob.core.windows.net/devphotos/ff69f2ad-fd1e-48ed-9ea8-f85e65639165.mp4

Same file uploaded to dropbox (which works):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ftbwgavjptq9vq/ff69f2ad-fd1e-48ed-9ea8-f85e65639165%20%281%29.mp4?dl=1

I'm playing the file by writing these lines:

```
string videoUri = _helpRequest.VideoURL;
_videoView.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(videoUri));
```

I'm thinking that I've run into a bug on Android 6.0 which doesn't allow the "cloudadvice.blob.core.windows.net" in the url. Anyone tried something like this or know what might be wrong? Maybe someone got a workaround?

This is the output from the log:

> 06-21 11:08:46.772 D/MediaHTTPConnection(20417):
>   filterOutInternalHeaders: key=User-Agent, val= SonyD5803
>   Build/23.5.A.0.575 stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 6.0.1)
>
> 06-21 11:08:46.773 D/MediaHTTPConnection(20417):
>   filterOutInternalHeaders: key=x-wap-profile, val=
>   http://uaprof.sonymobile.com/D5803R2331.xml
>
> 06-21 11:08:46.774 D/MediaHTTPConnection(20417): proxy null port 0
>
> 06-21 11:08:47.113 W/MediaHTTPConnection(20417): readAt 392002 / 32768
>   => java.net.ProtocolException
>
> 06-21 11:08:47.114 E/NuCachedSource2(  390): source returned error
>   -1010, 0 retries left 06-21 11:08:47.114 W/NuCachedSource2(  390): mFinalStatus: -1010, returning ERROR_UNSUPPORTED
>
> 06-21 11:08:47.114 E/QCExtractor(  390):  ExtendedExtractor failed to
>   instantiate extractor
>
> 06-21 11:08:47.115 E/GenericSource(  390): Failed to init from data
>   source!
>
> 06-21 11:08:47.115 D/NuPlayerDriver(  390):
>   notifyListener_l(0xa9dc9300), (100, 1, -2147483648)
>
> 06-21 11:08:47.115 E/MediaPlayer(20417): error (1, -2147483648)
>
> 06-21 11:08:47.122 E/MediaPlayer(20417): Error (1,-2147483648)
>
> 06-21 11:08:47.122 D/VideoView(20417): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: Can you post the exception shown in the log?

Comment: Double checked my phone and its running 6.0.1.

I found this issue with status released, but it doesn't seem to have been fixed:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191218

Comment: Add posts from log